# What problem causes exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005) while pyqtSignal.emit()?

Tags: pyqt5, qrunnable

I use pyqt5 and python 3.9 in PyCharm.
This is my minimal code

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, QRunnable, pyqtSignal, QThreadPool
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication


class Launcher(QRunnable, QObject):
    test_signal = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def run(self):
        print("This will be printed!")
        self.test_signal.emit()


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        launcher = Launcher()
        launcher.test_signal.connect(self.sayHi)
        self.threadpool = QThreadPool()
        self.threadpool.start(launcher)

    def sayHi(self):
        print("Hi")  # This won't be printed


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()

    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

And I get an error
`Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)`

What should I do to avoid it?
I dont get this error if my test_signal is independent class nested from QObject. But I dont understand the difference between this pyqtSignal instances.

Comment: Qt doesn't play well with multiple inheritance and QObject. If you need to emit signals, then create a QObject subclass that does that, create an instance in the other object and make it a member, then emit it whenever required. Alternatively, if you don't need the benefits of QThreadPool and QRunnable, use QThreads instead.

Comment: @musicamante Where can I read more about Qt limitations like that? it's pretty not obvious

Comment: https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/gotchas.html